# Getting Error Of Connectivity In Appium Server

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

> info: [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m [90m{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"D:\My_ALOHA\Appium\TestProject\apps\demo1.apk","platform":"VISTA","platformVersion":"4.4.3","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"AppiumDemo123","browserName":"","app-package":"com.livestrong.calorietracker","app-activity":"com.livestrong.calorietracker.activities.WelcomeActivity","version":"4.4.2"}}[39m
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : platform, app-package, app-activity, version
>   info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: D:\My_ALOHA\Appium\TestProject\apps\demo1.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 72fe50ca-03c4-4b3d-b3a4-683a47984b62
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
>   error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing: "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows (192.168.8.159)\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...

Answer (score 0):

Your appActivity and appPackage capabilities are missing. Please add this to your capabilities class:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", packageName);
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", activityName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote you activity and package capabilities in the wrong format.  Copy and paste the below code.  it should be "appPackage" or "app-Package" same for activity.

capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.livestrong.calorietracker");
           capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.livestrong.calorietracker.activities.WelcomeActivity");

Also, make sure to have debug mode turned on in developer mode of your phone because it seems Android adb couldn't detect your phone.