# Appium : Could not find a connected Android device.

Tags: python, appium

I am using Appium for automation testing on Android device using python code. It's working on other PC's but on windows 7 after executing `mycode.py` file using appium server throwing error but `adb devices` showing device is connected and also same device name is used in code:

Python : **WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while process
ing the command. Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.**

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python>adb devices
List of devices attached
06XXXXXXXXX96        device
```

> Appium Log :
>
> [debug] [ADB] Restarting adb
>   [ADB] Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
>
> Error:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "android.py", line 26, in setUp
>      self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 36, i
>   n **init**
>      super(WebDriver, self).**init**(command_executor, desired_capabilities, brow
>   ser_profile, proxy, keep_alive)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
>   ine 92, in **init**
>      self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
>   ine 179, in start_session
>      response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
>   ine 236, in execute
>      self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
>   , line 192, in check_response
>      raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while process
>   ing the command. Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.
>
> ---
>
> Ran 1 test in 22.456s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)
>   so

I tried solutions from [Getting Error Of Connectivity In Appium Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457076/getting-error-of-connectivity-in-appium-server)  / [Log In
Appium error connecting android device](https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-error-connecting-android-device/4711/9) / [Appium session, could not find a connected Android device. Shows error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127105/appium-session-could-not-find-a-connected-android-device-shows-error)  but not working for me.

Comment: did you set ANDROID_HOME path?

Comment: @Vinod ANDROID_HOME  is set.